# Characterization of the Levi-Civita connection through length-extremization property of geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections, semi-riemannian-geometry

I know that geodesics on a Riemannian manifold equipped with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ have two equivalent characterizations:

1. They are *energy-extremizing* curves (which is equivalent to being *length-extremizing* and being parametrized as to have *constant velocity*, of course w.r.t. the same background metric) ;
2. They are *self-parallel* curves (i.e. the velocity vector of the curve is parallel transported along the curve) with respect to $\nabla$.

I'd like to know if this equivalence characterizes the Levi-Civita connection: given a Riemannian manifold equipped with a generic torsion-free connection $\nabla$, is it true that the equivalence of properties (1) and (2) forces $\nabla$ to be the Levi-Civita connection?
(I guess the restriction to torsion-free connections is needed because only the symmetric part of the Christoffel symbol enters the geodesic equation.)

I am also curious about the possibility of weakening the hypotheses: is just one of the implications (e.g (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1)) enough to force $\nabla$ to be the Levi-Civita connection?

Finally, do these results carry over to metrics with a Lorentzian $(+---)$ signature or is a positive-definite metric essential? (I guess in this case we could restrict to 'timelike' curves, i.e. curves whose velocity vector $v$ satisfies $g(v,v) > 0$ everywhere, to ensure the length functional and its variation are real.)

If possible, I would appreciate proofs avoiding the explicit computation of the Christoffel symbols or the coordinate expression of the geodesic equation.

Comment: What you think you know is not quite right because the extrimization property is independent of the parameterization. You have to add the constant speed assumption for these properties to be equivalent. As for your question itself: you should clarify that the curves in question have constant speed and are length-extremizing with respect to the same background Riemannian metric.

Comment: Using the Levi-Civita connection, a curve is self-parallel if and only if it is locally energy minimizing. As @MoisheKohan points out, length minimizing is not enough. It is straightforward to show that if the connection is not torsion free, then this fact is no longer true. The no-Christoffel-symbol calculation is straightforward, but if you find it elusive, I do recommend methodically writing it all out using local coordinates and Christoffel symbols. You can always translate it back into modern notation afterwards.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you for pointing this out, I should have mentioned the parametrization. I also tried to follow your suggestion and make the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks to @Deane too, for mentioning the energy characterization. I hope i fixed the error and made the question correct and clearer now.

Comment: Have you tried to answer the question? Perhaps you could show what you’ve tried so far?